# configure parent/child relationship between 2 Custom Post Type only in child

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, relation

I would like to create a relationship between 2 Custom Post Type avoiding that the user has to go to both to create the link.

In absolute terms, I would like the user to go to only one Custom Post Type (writing) which remains fairly basic: A title field, a text field, an image field, a link field for documents or url, and finally a selector field to select its parent (created with ACF).

In the hierarchy of the site, these posts created are at the end of the race, therefore, are only post children. They will display with "single.php".

The site obviously contains different menus which also have different sub-menus, a front-page.php for the home page, for the main menus we have the archive pages and for the sub-menus of the single pages.

The other Custom Post Types are the site menus which each contain their respective submenus. The user doesn't have to go here, hence I would like to create a parent/child relationship only by going into the child Custom Post Type.

For example, in my home page (front-page.php), I have a "Company" part if I click on it, I arrive on "archive.creb.php" where there is "Office", Secretariat" and "Management", if I click on "Office" I arrive on "single.creb.php", in this part, there is "the team" and "the calendar", if I click on "the team", I arrive at "single.php".

The team page (just like the "calendar" page) is an article written by the user.

So I'm looking for a way so that, when the user creates an article, he can choose where it will be (with the ACF selector field), and therefore choose its parent AND in addition, that the link of the article appears in this parent.

I know how to do this kind of operation by configuring a relational field in the 2 Custom Post Types concerned with ACF, but not with just one.

I did some research, especially on the ACF doc and I found this:

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

So I tried to adapt the ACF example with my code, but it's not easy because it's not quite the same... By schematizing the ACF example to mine, it gives this:

[image: schematization relationship hierarchy of ACF and me]

In both cases there is indeed a selection field creation, except that in the ACF example its selector chooses the child and I choose the parent. So I tried to reverse, using the code from single.location.php in my single.creb.php.... But it doesn't work.. my single.creb.php page shows a link loop to himself

So... I hope I was clear in my question! Hoping for an answer

Here are some codes :

functions.php

```
function custom_post_type(){
    $arg = [
        'public'=> true,
        'label'=> 'CREB',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports'=>array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'has_archive'=>true,
        'menu_icon'=> 'dashicons-groups'
    ];
    register_post_type('creb', $arg);

    $arg = [
        'public'=> true,
        'label'=> 'redaction',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'supports'=>array('title', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'has_archive'=>true,
        'menu_icon'=> 'dashicons-book-alt'
    ];
    register_post_type('redaction', $arg);

}
add_action('init', 'custom_post_type');
```

single-creb.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- single creb -->
<main id="" class="">
    <div class="">
        <h1 class="">single CREB</h1>
        <?php
            if(have_posts()){
                while(have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    the_title();
                    $redac = get_field('textesousmenu');
                    if($redac){
                        echo $redac;
                    };
                };
            };
        ?>    
    </div>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

single.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- single creb -->
<main id="" class="">
    <div class="">
        <h1 class="">single</h1>
        <?php
            if(have_posts()){
                while(have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    the_title();
                    $redac = get_field('texte');
                    if($redac){
                        echo $redac;
                    };
                    $img = get_field('img');
                    if($img){
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image($img, 'modale');
                    }
                    if (have_rows('liendocurl')){?>
                        <ul class="">
                            <?php while (have_rows('liendocurl')){
                                the_row();
                                $nom = get_sub_field('nomlien');
                                $docurl = get_sub_field('urllien');?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $docurl; ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <?php echo $nom ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                           <?php } ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php } 
                    $lien = get_field('relation');
                    if($lien){?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            $name = get_the_title($lien->ID);
                            $link = get_permalink($lien->ID);
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $link;?>">
                                    <?php echo $name; ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>    
                        </ul><?php
                    }
                };
            };
        ?>    
    </div>
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Hey did you ever get this figured out? It looks like you put a lot of time and effort into creating a well-organized detailed post. It is disappointing to see that nobody replied.